A strange thing about vector<atomic<bool>> under multi-thread circumstance in C++
I was using vector<atomic<bool>> in C++, the code is here:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    int count = 20;
    vector<atomic<bool>> flags(n);
    vector<thread> jobs;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        jobs.emplace_back([&](){
            bool old_val = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (flags[i].compare_exchange_strong(old_val, true)) {
                    cout<<1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        jobs[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}

I don't know why, no matter what the value of variable count is, the output content is always "11111", which means that the compare_exchange_strong() only succeeds 5 times, half of the length of the vector<atomic<bool>>.
I expect the output would be 1111111111(ten 1s).
Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!!!!

The values of the vector vector<atomic<bool>> flags(10); are not initialized. I'm not sure what values are being stored in it then. What output were you expecting?

@Ivan "The values of the vector vector<atomic> flags(10); are not initialized...." I don't think that is correct. In general, std::vector<T> var(10); does initialize the elements. The elements are zero initialized for most cases.

A side note: instead of the magic number in flags(10) and i<10 you probably wanted to use n (which is unused at the moment).

@Ivan It can't be initialized, but the values are false by default, I expect the output would be "1111111111"（ten 1s） when the number of threads is enough.

@Wohlstad Yes, thank you, the parameter n should replace the number 10 in flags(10), I forgot it.

@user12002570 It would be more accurate to say that elements are default-initialized (for any T). But indeed for built-in types, it will result in zero initialization.

@wohlstad Done! Thank you! How careless am I...

@Fareanor You meant value-initialized.

output stream isn't synchronized tough... it's much better to collect results first

@wohlstad It seems like the problem lies in the variable old_val, it would be turned into true in the compare_exchange_strong(), if the code is if (!old_val && flags[i].compare_exchange_strong(old_val, true)) , the output is 1111111111. But I don't know why the output is five 1s if the !old_val condition is removed.

@Swift-FridayPie individual calls to std::cout are synchronised so cout << num is ok, it's only things like cout << num << "\n" where there are multiple operations that you'll get unexpected output with multiple threads

@AlanBirtles well, as we output only 1 it's fine, but if we do some kind of counter on some implementations they wouldn't have definite order related to how threads worked. And I ran into implementation where multi-character output gets broken (on a Raspberry Pi).

I think a vector of atomics is not itself atomic or thread-safe !

Your threads are in a race with each other but not for thread-safety reasons. What we see is a perfectly mathematical statistic of flipping vaue to "yes" and "no" (and sometimes it's done intentionally).
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 2;
    int count = 4;
    vector<atomic<bool>> flags(n);
    vector<thread> jobs;
    atomic<int> k  {};

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout  << flags[i] << " ";
    } 
    cout << "\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        jobs.emplace_back([&,i](){
            bool old_val = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (flags[j].compare_exchange_strong(old_val, true)) {
                    string s = to_string(i) + " :" + to_string(j) + "-" +  to_string(k++) + "(1)\t ";
                    cout << s;
                    break;
                } else {
                    string s = to_string(i) + " :" + to_string(j) + "-" +  to_string(k++) + "(0)\t ";
                    cout << s;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        jobs[i].join();
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout  << flags[i] << " ";
    } 
    return 0;
}

Output:
0 0 
0 :0-0(1)    1 :0-1(0)   1 :1-2(0)   2 :0-3(0)   2 :1-4(0)   3 :0-5(0)   3 :1-6(0)   
1 0  

Do you see what's going on? compare_exchange_strong got a side-effect upon it's  argument, it save detected value. It's a state race (not to be confused with racing condition), because even if other thread "flips" the flag, your thread skips it and then skips next one because it wants to find 1.

Atomically compares the object representation(until C++20)value
representation(since C++20) of *this with that of expected. If those
are bitwise-equal, replaces the former with desired (performs
read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, loads the actual value stored
in *this into expected (performs load operation).

Your code should be:
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bool old_val = false;
            if (flags[i].compare_exchange_strong(old_val, true)) {
                cout<<1;
                break;
            }
        }


You're reusing the same variable for each exchange, so if flags[i] is true on the first iteration, old_flags will be true on the second.
Then, if flags[i] is false on the third iteration, old_flags becomes false again.
This flip-flopping means that you only modify every other element in flags.
Move the declaration bool old_val = false; inside the loop.

Thank you!!!! Another question is, if I want to make sure that the old value is false, how can I pass a lvalue with a false value to compare_exchange_strong()?

@yilincai You can't. Overwriting it is half the "exchange" part of "compare and exchange".

@yilincai: Putting bool old_val = false; inside the inner loop like this answer says will re-initialize it to false before every CAS_strong.  You could just use bool old_val = flags[i].exchange(true); to unconditionally store true and read the old value.  On some ISAs that might perform differently than a CAS if the value was already true, but on x86 lock cmpxchg always dirties the cache line even if the compare failed.  (Does cmpxchg write destination cache line on failure? If not, is it better than xchg for spinlock?)
